# How to change the order of rsync in symfony deployment task

Tags: deployment, symfony1, task, rsync

I want to deploy a part of my symfony application, say, it's like a module.

> *I want to exclude all files first, and then include only the files of
>   my new module.*

For deployment I use the following symfony task

```
 php symfony project:deploy production -t
```

The parameter -t prints all files to the output that are included in this dry run of rsync.

Content of config/rsync_exclude.txt is only *, since I like to exclude everthing:

```
*
```

In config/rsync_include.txt I list all the files and folders for the inclusion:

```
config/
config/mysupermodule.yml
lib/model/doctrine/
lib/model/doctrine/MySuperclass.php
lib/model/doctrine/MySuperclassTable.php
lib/
lib/MySuperLibrary/
lib/MySuperLibrary/*
```

The symfony task builds the following rsync command:

```
rsync --dry-run -azC --force --delete --progress --exclude-from=config/rsync_exclude.txt --include-from=config/rsync_include.txt -e "ssh -p22" ./ user@www.server.com:/test_deployment/
```

**Problem 1:  The the task doesn't sync any files.**

**Solution to 1: Change order: Include first, then exclude.**

I figured out, that if I change my need to this one:

> *I want to include all files of my new module and exclude then all
>   other.*

This means using the following command:

```
rsync --dry-run -azC --force --delete --progress --include-from=config/rsync_include.txt --exclude-from=config/rsync_exclude.txt -e "ssh -p22" ./ user@www.server.com:/test_deployment/
```

The rsync works.

**Problem 2: How can I change the order of the rsync when using the symfony task?**
The symfony task first excludes than includes.

**Solution 2: ?**

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT possible.

But you can edit the deployment task in `lib/task/project/sfProjectDeployTask.class.php`.

Replace this (line 145 to 154 in SF 1.4):

```
  if (file_exists($options['rsync-dir'].'/rsync_exclude.txt'))
  {
    $parameters .= sprintf(' --exclude-from=%s/rsync_exclude.txt', $options['rsync-dir']);
  }

  if (file_exists($options['rsync-dir'].'/rsync_include.txt'))
  {
    $parameters .= sprintf(' --include-from=%s/rsync_include.txt', $options['rsync-dir']);
  }
```

with this:

```
  if (file_exists($options['rsync-dir'].'/rsync_include.txt'))
  {
    $parameters .= sprintf(' --include-from=%s/rsync_include.txt', $options['rsync-dir']);
  }

  if (file_exists($options['rsync-dir'].'/rsync_exclude.txt'))
  {
    $parameters .= sprintf(' --exclude-from=%s/rsync_exclude.txt', $options['rsync-dir']);
  }
```

In short: switch this two IF statements.

Comment: thank you, I did this before, but I did not want to touch the class actually. Good answer!

Comment: I can't vote up, not enough reputation. But I think, it's because the proposition to change a file in the framework is not the right way. I would extend the class sfProjectDeployTask and implement the changed here. Anyway the idea is correct and the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the way you want to do.
You should use only the exclude file. Exclude only directories that changed but you don't want to sync.

Because anyway if you modules/,  app/, ... directories haven't change, you don't have to put them in the exclude file because they will remain the same on both server.